# How to build and save Parent and Child records when required = true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given the following models

```
class Parent
  has_many :children
end
class Child
  belongs_to :parent, required: true
end
```

Is it possible to create Parent and Children at the same time?

```
@parent = Parent.new(valid_attributes)
@parent.children.build(valid_attributes)
@parent.save
@parent.errors.messages 
#=> {:"children.parent"=>["must exist"]}
```

Removing the `required: true` allows the record to save. But is there a way to enable parents and children to be saved together while still validating parent exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use  `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, Enabling nested attributes on association allows you to create the parent and child in one go.

Model **parent.rb**

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children

  #enable nested attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end
```

Model **child.rb**

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

Build and save your object **parents_controller.rb**

```
class ParentsController < ApplicationController

   def new
     @parent = Parent.new
     @parent.children.build

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html # new.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @parent }
     end
   end

   def create
      #your params should look like.
      params = { 
        parent: {
          name: 'dummy parent', 
          children_attributes: [
            { title: 'dummy child 1' },
            { title: 'dummy child 2' }
          ]
        }
      }

      #You can save your object at once.
      @parent = Parent.create(params[:parent])

      #Or you can set object attributes manually and then save it.
      @parent.name = params[:parent][:name]
      @parent.children_attributes = params[:parent][:children_attributes]
      @parent.save
   end  

end
```

> For more info:
>   http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Your on the right track but the proper plural of child is children not childs. This matters in rails as it will mess up inflection. There are several syntax errors as well.

Comment: Thanks @max for pointing this out, i have updated my answer. Please let me know where i am using wrong syntax?

Comment: See my edit. There was a space between colon and children in two places.

Comment: thanks @satendra and @max, this is very useful. I was already using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, however your answer helped me realize that I was not building the children correctly. As an aside, how do you inspect the built child attributes? `@parent.children` obviously does not work until after save. `@parent.children_attributes` is not a valid getter method. `@parent.attributes` does not include the hash of children. What am I missing?